# Having trouble getting user input into array without getting errors

Tags: java

I am creating a roommate bill splitter program and do not know what I am doing wrong.  It gets hung up after asking what the roommates names are.  Output is below code.

```
package roomBillSplit;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to Roommate Bill Splitter!\n");
        
        //Get Residence Name from User
        System.out.print("Please Enter Name of Place or Address:  ");
        String place = input.nextLine();

        roommates(place);           
        bills(place);
        input.close();
    }
       
    public static void roommates(String place) {
        int numRoom, i;
     
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Get # of Roommates at Residence
        System.out.print("How Many Total People Reside at " + place + ":  ");
        numRoom = input.nextInt();
        
        String[] roommates = new String[numRoom];
        //ArrayList<String> roommates = new ArrayList<String>(5);

        //Get Names of Roommates
        for(i = 0; i < roommates.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("What is Person Number " + (i + 1) + "'s Name:  ");
            if(input.hasNext()) {
                roommates[i] = input.nextLine();
                input.next();
            }
        }
        
        for(i = 0; i < roommates.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(roommates[i]);
            }
            input.close();
        }
    }

    public static void bills(String place) {
        int numBills, i;
     
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     
        //Get # of Bills Split Between Roommates
        System.out.print("What is the Total Number of Bills to be Split at " + place + ":  ");
        numBills = input.nextInt();
        
        String[] bills = new String[numBills];
        
        //Get Names of Bills
        for(i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please List Bill Number " + (i + 1) + ":  ");
            if(input.hasNext()) {
                bills[i] = input.nextLine();
                input.next();
            }
        }
        
        for(i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(bills[i]);
        }
        
        int amount[] = new int[numBills];
        
        //Get Amount of Each Bill
        for(i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("What is the Total Amount of the " + bills[i] + " Bill:  $");
            if(input.hasNextInt()) {
                amount[i] = input.nextInt(); 
                input.next();
            }
        }
                
        input.close();
        
        for(i = 0; i < amount.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(bills[i]);
            System.out.print("\t$");
            System.out.println(amount[i]);
        }  
    }
}
```

Output:

> Welcome to Roommate Bill Splitter!
>
> Please Enter Name of Place or Address:  1212 Main
>
> How Many Total People Reside at 1212 Main:  2
>
> What is Person Number 1's Name:  a
>
> What is Person Number 2's Name:  b
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>
> at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>
> at roomBillSplit.Main.bills(Main.java:62)
>
> at roomBillSplit.Main.main(Main.java:19)
>
> What is the Total Number of Bills to be Split at 1212 Main:

Comment: Don't close the `Scanner`

Comment: Ok, I was told that I needed to close the scanner, but it seems to work now until I get to the part where I am asked to enter the amount of the bills.  Then it seems to go through and infinite loop or something.                

Please Enter Name of Place or Address:  1212
How Many Total People Reside at 1212:  2
What is Person Number 1's Name:  g
What is Person Number 2's Name:  d


What is the Total Number of Bills to be Split at 1212:  3
Please List Bill Number 1:  rent
Please List Bill Number 2:  ele
Please List Bill Number 3:  cable



What is the Total Amount of the  Bill:  $200

Comment: Also, you're checking for one string token, then pulling off the entire line and another token after that.  I expect there's simply no data when you try the unchecked `nextList()` or `next()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program waiting for user input. If you press any key it will resume. This is because

You have extra `input.next()` in remove that line it will work.

```
//Get Names of Roommates
    for(i = 0; i < roommates.length; i++){
        System.out.print("What is Person Number " + (i + 1) + "'s Name:  ");
            if(input.hasNext()){
               roommates[i] = input.nextLine();
               input.next();
            }
    }
```

UPDATE:

You don't need to use `input.hasNext()` and `input.next()` because `input.nextLine()` will block for the user input.

Comment: When I remove the input.next() it will ask for the first user input, then it will just print the "enter user input #2" on the same line, not wait for a user response and move to the next "enter user input #3".  It does wait for the last user input, but skips the 2nd one.  It is still getting hung up after the first user input for the entering the bill amount.  It also does not display the bill name from the user input when asking for the amount.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH...IVE BEEN STEWING OVER THIS FOR A WEEK!  If I have further question about the same code, should I post here or create new thread?

Comment: @tjgpp9 you create a new one. If it solves your problem Vote & Accept my answer. it makes me feel happy.. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you close the Scanner at the end of your roommates method, you also close System.in, so you can't scan from it any more when you need it in your bills method, and that's why your new Scanner there doesn't work.

Pass the Scanner you create in your main method as an argument to your roommates and bills method, instead of having those methods create a new Scanner, and remove all of the input.close() statements except for the one in main.

Edited to add:
It will fix your other problem if you change how you are reading from the scanner inside of your loops to look like this:

```
...
roommates[i] = input.next();
input.nextLine();
...
bills[i] = input.next();
input.nextLine();
...
amount[i] = input.nextInt(); 
input.nextLine();
...
```

Comment: Does it need to be input.nextInt(); on the last one?

Comment: The last line in each of these needs to be input.nextLine() to clear out the new line character from the user pressing enter.